Why does Firefox delays requests with angular proxy?
Often requests under the proxy have 2 seconds Blocked and 2 seconds Connecting resulting in a 4 seconds delay.
Steps to reproduce:

Create ASP.NET Core Web API.
Create new angular project.
Add proxy.conf.json to angular's /src.

{
  "/WeatherForecast": {
    "target": "https://localhost:7256",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}


Add to angular.json "serve"

"options": {
  "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.mjs"
}


Add to app.component button with click:

<button (click)="click()">click</button>

constructor(private http: HttpClient){ }

click(){
  this.http.get('/WeatherForecast').subscribe();
}


Run API.
Run ng serve and open http://localhost:4200 in Firefox.
Open Network and click on the button multiple times. Here're the results which are not observed in other browsers:



Is there anything wrong with the configuration itself?
What can be a reason of the delay?
What would be an appropriate place to report this behavior?


when it switches to HTTPS it may be checking for cert.  Just a guess.
